# Controlling Buck converter (XL4016) with microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, dc-dc-converter, buck

Briefly the project I'm working on is made up of a blue pill, rotary encoder, acs712 30 amp current sensor and an OLED display. Everything is in functional state. The aim is to provide a stable controllable voltage starting from a 4s (16.8v max) lithium, BMSed, battery. At start I tought I could just use a good MOSFET and smooth that out with a filter on the output. Later on I discovered these xl4016 modules around the web [Xl4016 module](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Electric-Unit-High-quality-C-D-C-CC-CV-Buck-Converter-Step-down-Power-Module/32807999591.html?spm=2114.search0204.3.62.5bed21c97Td2Kr&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_1_10065_10068_319_317_10696_453_10084_454_10083_433_10618_431_10304_10307_10820_10821_537_10302_536_10902_10843_10059_10884_10887_100031_321_322_10103,searchweb201603_56,ppcSwitch_0&algo_expid=a4986eb1-a34a-4a48-8185-57c66f5a02b9-9&algo_pvid=a4986eb1-a34a-4a48-8185-57c66f5a02b9&transAbTest=ae803_3)([xl4016 datasheet](http://www.xlsemi.com/datasheet/xl4016%20datasheet.pdf)) that give 8 amps (which is a good start, there's also a 12 amp model) and these seems to give a stable output without much hassle. So the plan now is to control the vari-volt which on the board is made by a potentiometer.
Looking around for a solution I found some possibilities:

- generate a pwm signal, smooth it out trought a low pass filter, and feed it to feedback pin trough an opamp in voltage follower mode.
- use a digital potentiometer (don't know if there's one up to spec)
- use a DAC such as mcp4275

**So the question is which one is the right way?**

Additionally, **tapping in the feedback pin could interfere with** the xl4016 **feedback mechanism.** So the aim would be also keep that voltage stable (between 0-12v) even though battery is discharging, so I somehow should sense the battery voltage and the output voltage? In the project every cell voltage is monitored trough voltage dividers. Can I just use an external ADC?
Thanks for the attention, and just ask for whatever is needed to provide an answer.

Update:
[image: datasheet]
here in the datasheet I can see : Vout = 1,25 (FBK) * (1+R2/R1) ----> if we put a fixed 10k resistor instead of the pot, can I inject voltage somehow on the feedback pin, maybe with a DAC? To get let's say a 12 V out following the formula it should be 2.97 V.

Comment: Your datasheet link is broken.

Comment: So you're trying to control the output voltage without having to turn the pot? That feedback voltage is fed to an Error Amplifier which compares it against a reference voltage. If you can find that reference voltage pin on that board you can cut the trace and use your uC DAC or an external DAC to make the reference voltage yourself.

Comment: Datasheet fixed.                                                                                   
 @Stiddily This is another viable way. But what would be the relation between? Or in other words, shouldnt this reference voltage be fixed as reference?

Comment: Your output voltage is checked against a reference voltage in the Error Amplifier. The output of the error amp is related to how far off your output voltage is from this reference. This is then fed into a PWM amp that compares that signal to a ramp and creates the PWM signal. If you lower the reference then you lower the output voltage required for the error amp to say you're at the right voltage. (If you want more info on how the feedback works let me know, but I don't want to go off topic. I design power supplies for a living so I like to talk lol).

Comment: @Stiddily If you have more info on the feedback glad to hear. I updated the post with typical application. To me it looks that the pot on the board is used to vary the voltage to the feedback pin. So assuming i can inject a clean and stable voltage to the feedback pin I can mostly regulate everything. Following the formula and keeping fixed 10k and 3.3k resistances, with a 3,3v max out I would likely be able to arrive to vout= 3,3* 4,03= 13,29 v which is perfect because I need 12v max. So your suggestion is to use a DAC or I can follow other routes?

Comment: I just noticed that you're trying to go from 3.3V up to 12V. If you get 3.3V @ 8A then you will only be able to pull 12V @ roughly 2A. That is if the components are rated for that much voltage. They could be using 6.3V caps! I'd suggest getting a 12V supply instead.

As for the feedback, the error amplifier is what controls stability and is the main backbone of an analog smps. There is voltage mode control and current mode control. Look up Type2 and Type3 compensators. Type2 is used for PCMC, but voltage mode needs Type 3 because of the extra pole. Don't have much space to type in comments!

Comment: @Stiddily No! The system in supplied by a 4s 25A battery! With 2 ldo i get 5v and 3.3v for my f103 microcontroller. The step down module gets 16.8 from the battery hence shares ground with bluepill as well as the dac that will be powered with a stable voltage of 3.3 (the same ldo). So we have a reference! Following the datasheet, feedback pin goes from -0,3 to Vin so we can feed voltage with our dac. This obviously if I understood it well.

Comment: The range I want is  more or less 0-1v to 12v starting from a 16,8 v battery everything trough the module linked in OP that is a stepdown with 8A maximum current.

Comment: if you replace the feedback with another voltage source, the converter won't see voltage drops due to load (having no feedback), in other words it will be basically unregulated. you could use a digipot, if you mind the voltages. If you need precise control, consider a series pass transistor following the buck

Comment: @dandavis can you please explain the two possibilities deeper? I quite don't understand. The digipot is a problem for dealing above 5v I think.

Comment: if you use the digipot as the bottom half of a voltage divider, it should never see more than the ref voltage, which is usually around 0.6v-1.5v. You can drive an NPN with a DAC or lowpass+PWM feeding an opamp, which you supply with the output of the buck. You float the buck a volt or two above the NPN's output, minimizing heat while allowing precise linear control. Think of the buck as a multi-tap transformer in an old-school setup, but with LOTS of taps...

Comment: @dandavis so the point is to use the digipot as it was r1 in the circuit shown right? Than instead of varying r2 which should be the pot onboard, I switch that to a fixed and use the digipot to the same vout relation? This way the buck will still be able to use its feedback. The npn parte I don't understand and as well as, will it survive 8A?

Comment: lookup "simple npn voltage regulator" or "series pass transistor" or "simple linear power supply"; replace the transformer and bridge+smoothing with your buck. adjust the buck to keep it 1-2v above the output. You should only need a few components; NPN, lowpass,  opamp, resistors and caps.

Comment: you might look over https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/167096/146704 ; it seems to present a simple way of controlling buck output via a small amount of voltage. I've tried it just now on an XL4015 using a 330r resistor to feed 0-3.3v to the Vset pot, which lets me swing the output from 16v-1.5v (not zero). The voltage on the resistor max at about 2v either way while consuming under 5ma, so it _should_ be safe to feed directly from a DAC or PWM+lowpass filter. It''s working for me, and I'm excited, i've been wanting this for years! See also: https://youtu.be/-W3eWJU-2Do?t=493

Comment: @dandavis  ok next week I'll try that with a dac and report back. The vout equation reported should consider 1.25 and not 0.8 right?

Comment: it depends on the buck's ref voltage, they are all somewhere in that range.

Comment: @dandavis but , I mean, should the voltage just be kept stable?

Comment: yes, you set the analog pot to the max output, then connect the new adjustable 0-3.3v voltage source. Providing 0v will yield max from the buck, 3.3v will output the low end of the buck's range. you don't have to monitor the voltage to set a stable and regulated output, you just set it and forget it.

Comment: https://www.fischl.de/dcdccontrol/ this is the best tutorial so far